# C# Prevent async task from being run again before finishing

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I cant seem to find the information that im looking for [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) and could use a second pair of eyes. I would like to do this without testing; only a visual examination and theory discussion.

My draft attempt sets a bool which will only allow an async method to be run if the returned task sets its value to `Task.IsCompleted`. My question is, will this code do what I assume it will and if not, what is an alternative that will perform only a single call at a time? (assuming the infinite loop and async task remain unchanged)

You may fairly assume that `RunAsync()` is an asynchronous method, denoted by the async keyword, containing an awaitable task which returns a `Task` instance.

```
bool asyncOutputCallAllowed = true;

while (true)
{           
    if (asyncOutputCallAllowed)
    {
        asyncOutputCallAllowed = false;
        asyncOutputCallAllowed = RunAsync().IsCompleted;
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve here. You want to create a chain of async calls, where you make the next call when the previous one completes?

Comment: In this code, `IsCompleted` will probably always be `false`. Do you want to *queue up* calls, or just *drop* them if it's already running?

Comment: The only way this could ever reset `asyncOutputCallAllowed` to `true` is if `RunAsync()` synchronously returns a completed task.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Can you tell us what the underlying issue is?

Comment: @odyss-jii that is correct. A chain of calls where only one call is performing at any one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you are trying to do the following: make an async call, keep looping and doing other stuff while also waiting for async-task to finish, and then start a new async task when the previous one finishes. If so, then you probably want something along the following lines:

```
Task activeOperation = null;
while (true)
{
    if (activeOperation == null)
    {
        // No async operation in progress. Start a new one.
        activeOperation = RunAsync();
    }
    else if (activeOperation.IsCompleted)
    {
        // Do something with the result.

        // Clear active operation so that we get a new one
        // in the next iteration.
        activeOperation = null;
    }

    // Do some other stuff
}
```

Depending on your exact algorithm, you might want to start the new task in the same iteration in which the previous one finishes. That is just a small tweak of the above.

If you are not doing anything else in the loop except wait for the async-task, then you can get rid of the loop entirely and use a continuation instead (see `ContinueWith`).

Comment: For me the key takeaway is that my code can only ever RunAsync() once since the IsCompleted boolean is immediately evaluated, after starting the async call. This is assuming returned task objects will have their reference updated on call completion. Would you agree with that statement?

Comment: This link confirms that it will work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted(v=vs.110).aspx